# How to create bridge with hostapd

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, bridge, hostapd

I want to bridge traffic between wired eth and WiFi interfaces in the same PC. WiFi interface I want to operate as access point. I use hostapd for it.
Using brctl I create bridge and add eth0 interface. But when I add wlan0 (WiFi interface) the transmission over wired LAN hangs.
So what is proper procedure to create such bridge?

Comment: you should add more information to your question: how are you creating the bridge and adding the interfaces, how are you starting hostapd, etc. Are you assigning an ip address to the bridge?

Answer (score 2):

Are you adding `wlan0` to the bridge before you bring up `hostapd` or after?

The best way to do it normally is to have `hostapd` add the wireless interface to the bridge by including `bridge=brN` in your `hostapd.conf` file.

Comment: That's what I'm doing. But first I need to define a bridge. Using brctl, bridge is deifine, then I add to bridge eth0 interface and next interface wlan0. And at this moment the suspension is communicating with your computer. The computer itself works fine and after reboot connectivity is restored but in a bridge configuration no interface wlan0. What I am doing wrong?